# Will a robots.txt file with "disallow / " stop all crawling of my website?

Tags: webserver, robots.txt

I know the following will stop all bots from crawling my site

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

But what about something like this:

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10
# Directories
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /misc/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /profiles/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /themes/
# Files
Disallow: /CHANGELOG.txt
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /INSTALL.mysql.txt
Disallow: /INSTALL.pgsql.txt
Disallow: /INSTALL.sqlite.txt
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /INSTALL.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /MAINTAINERS.txt
Disallow: /update.php
Disallow: /UPGRADE.txt
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /comment/reply/
Disallow: /filter/tips/
Disallow: /node/add/
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /user/register/
Disallow: /user/password/
Disallow: /user/login/
Disallow: /user/logout/
# Paths (no clean URLs)
Disallow: /?q=admin/
Disallow: /?q=comment/reply/
Disallow: /?q=filter/tips/
Disallow: /?q=node/add/
Disallow: /?q=search/
Disallow: /?q=user/password/
Disallow: /?q=user/register/
Disallow: /?q=user/login/
Disallow: /?q=user/logout/

Disallow: /
```

I didn't want to comment out the entire file and logic told me that having the final Disallow: / line should override all the previous rules, but we got a report from the client that a form was submitted from the site this robots.txt file belongs to, leading us to believe it was indexed. Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks ya'll!

Comment: No matter what you put there, robots.txt will not *stop* indexing. It can only *instruct* bots not to do it. If the bot is malicious, it will almost certainly disregard robots.txt.

Comment: You might be better of using mod_rewrite for this.

Comment: _robots.txt_ compliance is strictly voluntary. There's nothing there to actually _keep_ a bot out of some area. It's just a request/suggestion that "well behaved" bots (e.g., major search engines) will obey.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the robots.txt file is no more than a request.
Polite web-crawlers will honor it, and potentially evil ones could ignore it or use it as a treasure map.
What you propose will work (to the extent that robots.txt work).

Here are the "rules":

- It needs to be readable by your webserver (duh, huh?)
- It needs to be at the root level of your webserver (e.g.
  (`http://www.example.com/robots.txt`).
- If you have multiple websites, each one needs a /robots.txt url (they
  can share the actual file, if appropriate).  Note that
  `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` are two
  different websites for these purposes as are `http://www.example.com`
  and `http://example.com`, even if they deliver the same content.
- The first match found applies (this is mostly important if you are
  using the non-standard, (but widely implemented) `Allow` extension).

You can find some additional information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard